# add constraint with condition

Tags: sql, check-constraints

I have a SQL table of X, Y and Z coordinates with two grid ID's WGS84_35N and WGS84_36N. The Min, Max X coordinates in WGS84_35N are between 500000 to 800000 and Min, Max X coordinates in WGS84_36N are in the range of 150000 to 300000. Would you please advise how can I limit the coordinates by using an SQL onstraint with the avove limit of X and Y in each gridID on the same table?

Kind regards,
Dinesh

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. In general, make it easy for us to help you, by showing effort, and focussing on a specific problem you are facing. It also helps if you list which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblDHcoll]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [chk_gridid_project_XY] 
CHECK (([Orig_Grid_ID]='WGS84_35N' AND ([Orig_East]>=(500000) and [Orig_East]<=(850000))))
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblDHColl] CHECK CONSTRAINT [chk_gridid_project_XY]
GO

Comment: Please add your code to the question. Also include any errors you get, or why this does not meet your requirements.

Comment: so you think is this query is correct and i should just check the database if there are some records that are outside the coordinates